# Tables Adjust Row width for th and td

Tags: html, css

I have a table and the `<th>` and `<td>` suppose be the same width, what I am doing wrong in my sass and css? the `nth-child(1)` and `nth-child(2)` suppose to have 20% and `nth-child(3)` 60% , what I am doing wrong? thank you.

sass code:

```
 table {
      th,td:nth-child(1),
      th,td:nth-child(2) {
        width: 20%;
      }
      th,td:nth-child(3) {
        width: 60%;
      }

      tr {
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        display: inline-table;
      }
  }
```

```css
table th, table td:nth-child(1),
table th, table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
table th, table td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Question with exact title you have already asked in the following link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801657/tables-adjust-row-width-for-th-and-td

Comment: these questions are not the same.

Comment: This can be done without CSS by setting the width on the TH's https://jsfiddle.net/eghgod1q/ just change the text alignment

Comment: @Gezzasa The `width` Attribute for tables is deprecated in HTML5, the CSS approach is correct here

Comment: @MatthiasS. thank you. I need to read up more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple solution:

Set table width to 100%

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  width: 20%;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}
```

Thats all

Comment: but this need to apply to th and td understand?

Comment: @Raduken, no, there is no need to apply width to td, in table the td always relative to th, whatever you give the width to th, the below td took the same

Answer (score 1):

You have a little "Bug" in your CSS logic. Your styles apply to every `th` inside of `table`, and only to the `nth-child` of the `td` Elements. So your `th` tags getting a width of 60%, because this is the last style and overwrites the ones before. To solve this, you could add the `nth-child` to the `th` Tags too, or remove the `th` completely, since they get the width of the `td` Elements below, when there is no specific width elsewhere. (Hope I could describe it, otherwise just ask :-) )

```css
table { width: 100%; }

table td:nth-child(1),
table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
table td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To be clear: Defining both th and td is pretty redundand, you could also just apply the styles to the th Tag, which will also work.

```
table th:nth-child(1),
table th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
table th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to define width to the ```td``` if you set the width if ```th``` in a table , and why to mention child 1 and 2, you can only mention the 3rd inky

Comment: Yeah, either you can remove the th or td styling, mentioned that in the answer (I try to make it clearer)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your CSS set up now is to only apply the :nth-child() rules to the `td`s. In order to apply it for the `th`s you need to add the same rule to it.

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}
table th:nth-child(1), table td:nth-child(1),
table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
table th:nth-child(3), table td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}

table th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

table td {
  background-color: #999;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added width in `th` instead of `td`

```css
table th:nth-child(1),
table th:nth-child(2){
  width: 20%;
}
table th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;  
}
table {
  width:100%;
}
table th {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
table td {
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 table th,td:nth-child(1),table th,td:nth-child(2) {
 width: 20%;
 text-align:center;}

 table th:nth-child(3),table td:nth-child(3) {
 width: 60%;
 text-align:center;}

 table {
    width: 100%; }
```